# Why has the checked attribute changed after firing the click event?

Tags: jquery, events, google-maps

I have this code:

```
siteCheckboxes.each(function () {

        var lat = $(this).attr("lat");
        var lng = $(this).attr("lng");
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ icon: smallDotIcon, position: myLatlng, map: map, title: $(this).attr("siteName") });
        var $checkbox = $(this);
        $(this).click(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("checked")) {

              marker.setIcon(null);  
            } else {
               marker.setIcon(smallDotIcon);

            }

        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
              $checkbox.click();
        });


    });
```

The idea is that I have several checkboxes with the name of sites and a map with small dot for each site on map. When user checked a site checkbox, the marker on map should changes to a full marker. This part of application works fine.

When user clicked on a marker, the status of related checkbox should changes and also the shape of marker, but it doesn’t work.

When user click on a marker, the checkbox checked state and marker shape became out of sync.What is the problem?

Some debugging showed me that if the user click on a marker, the click event of the marker called, and the click event of related checkbox is also called, but the checked state changes after checkbox click event finishes.

Why is it changes after click event finishes?

Comment: can you make jsfiddle ? but i think you need preventdefault in click handler

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're looping over all your checkboxes, creating your click handlers.  However when the user then clicks on any marker, it will always use the last value for $checkbox, not the one corresponding with when you created the marker eventlistener.

You need a closure.

Try something like this instead. Create a new top-level function, *bindClick*, outwith your .each loop.  In your .each loop, call that function.  This then creates the event listener with whatever checkbox you're looping over at the time.

```
siteCheckboxes.each(function () {
    var lat = $(this).attr("lat");
    var lng = $(this).attr("lng");
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ icon: smallDotIcon, position: myLatlng, map: map, title: $(this).attr("siteName") });
    var $checkbox = $(this);


    bindClick($checkbox, marker);
});


function bindClick(checkbox, marker) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
          checkbox.click();
    });
}
```